# DHCP packet received on wlan0 which has no address on pihole

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, open-source, adblock, pihole

I have setup my DHCP server with pihole, it's working fine.

I received this error on pi-Hole diagnosis.

[**Check the image here.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrtJ4.png)

Please help.

I tried nothing to resolve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you are using Pi-hole's embedded DHCP server. When running a diagnosis (using `pihole -d`), Pi-hole queries on each interface to check if a DHCP server responds there. Your Pi-hole's DHCP server received this request on `wlan0` which, however, isn't configured.

This is fine and nothing to worry about.